How useful is algebraic topology to computer science (Dieck vs Lee)?
Recently I've become interested in the learning about dynamical systems and their applications to computer science. However, on the road map, one of the prerequisites is a knowledge of algebraic topology. To learn algebraic topology, I have the opportunity to learn out of 2 books -  either the simpler Lee’s topological manifolds or the advanced Dieck’s algebraic topology. Typically, I would try to read the most comprehensive textbooks I can find (as I dislike having to redo subjects I’ve already had courses in). However, in this case I’m concerned that algebraic topology may be so far removed from computer science that I would be wasting my time by reading an advanced book like Dieck's. (Also checking dynamical systems textbooks there seems to be no algebraic topology beyond Lee’s book, adding to my concern of time wasting.)
So if anyone could help by explaining the importance of algebraic topology in computer science (especially automata theory) and whether it's enough to warrant an advanced textbook like Dieck's, it would be appreciated.

On the face of it, I would guess that the part of dynamical systems that requires algebraic topology is somewhat removed from the part that is relevant to automata.
More specifically, the most obvious applications of algebraic topology would be in dynamical systems with a continuous state space and a continuous time parameter (e.g., "what is the knot type of this closed orbit in 3-space") whereas automata are typically finite-state or at least discrete-state, and driven by a discrete clock.

Would you say that those applications to dynamical systems or other areas of computer science would require higher level algebraic topology like that found in dieck's book?

I am unfamiliar with that specific book. My general feeling is that you would be safe to start your study of dynamical systems directly. There would be a great deal to learn in that area before you even arrive at the part where algebraic topology might become useful. And perhaps, by that time, you have already learned the part of dynamical systems that allows you to apply them to automata.
